# VSFTPD - User and group is sometimes set to root:root

Tags: vsftpd

How can I change the user and group which uploaded files will have?
My Developer IDE (Netbeans) keeps failing to upload files because they are set to root:root instead of my FTP user and `www`.

This is my current config (**/etc/vsftpd.conf**)

```
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
ftpd_banner=Willkommen auf dem Entwicklungsserver
ls_recurse_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
chmod_enable=YES
file_open_mode=0777
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=YES
syslog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES

ssl_enable=NO
rsa_cert_file=
dsa_cert_file=
#
# Limit passive ports to this range to assis firewalling
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30100
```

Comment: I think this is related to modman which symlinks a folder to the main repo which changes the ownership